Using iframe to show pdf and open at a particular page by the given offset and also highlight any given text
I want to make a pdf viewer in which i want to open that pdf on a particular page by the given offset which will say on what text i want to show the pdf by default and also i need to highlight a particular text in that pdf. I have used iframe to open the pdf it is working but i have no idea how to do navigation and highlighting in pdf as my expectation.
           <iframe
              id="my-iframe"
              src="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/pdf/pdf-succinctly.pdf#page=3&zoom=FitH&search=Chapter 2 Building a PDF"
              loading="lazy"
              title="PDF Viewer"
              width="100%"
              height="100%"
            ></iframe>

I have tried this code to show pdf.pdf is visible on the page 3 but in my case i don't know about page number i only have offset and the given text to which i need to navigate and highlight.

does that mean #page=3#zoom=FitH#search=Chapter 2 Building a PDF is just a guess, or is it something documented somewhere?

For a reference on params use this. You use # only after the first param, for the rest you have to append them using &, search seems to work only on Firefox, and works only for single words

Using # before every parameter was just a guess. I saw some documentation they were using a single parameter so I thought maybe we need to put # before each parameter.

@LS_ The reference you provided is helpful. Search is working only on Firefox what should I do to make it support every browser?

@GulamMd That's up to the browser vendors to add support for the feature. An alternative could be to use a library like pdf.js to build your custom viewer. You can see an example here.

@LS_ So can I achieve text highlighting and page navigation by offset using pdf.js?

I don't know what you mean with offset, but if you look through the docs you should be able to find what you're looking for

You cannot combine such fragments to force an ordered sequence in any browser. For example that will not work in any Chromium based browser.
Your command was written in the style used long ago for Acrobat. So it should work in Acrobat Reader today. So like shown below in a browser such as Edge with Acrobat Reader (There are still a few using ActiveX). There are conflicts but it searches for separate words in your list of words, NEVER a phrase.
The "#search" rule is,

search=wordList
Opens the Search panel and performs a search for any of the words in the specified word list. The first matching word is highlighted in the document. The words must be enclosed in quotation marks and separated by spaces. For example: #search="word1 word2" You can search only for single words. You cannot search for a string of words."

There was also a highlight command, but have never seen that working this century. Firefox is about the closest to combining the pair of commands but not as you might expect. Neither work in current Chromium based PDF browsers (The majority).

Highlights a specified rectangle on the displayed page. Use the page command before this command.

This is what you seem to be attempting.

This is what your combined commands, will do in current Acrobat Reader in a browser.

For Chrome / Edge PDF plug-ins you will get conflicts, which then simply shows first page by default.

If you only request page 3, you will get page 3. For Firefox you will get a different result, if the controls are allowed by the user.
But I can not show  you that, since newer Firefox corrupts my device, thus I have deleted all versions for now! see How to enable PDF search option using embed or Iframe in HTML

For the majority of browsers which are either Mozilla PDF.js or Chromium based like Edge, you need a command to just fit page 13 (without any highlighting).
https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/pdf/pdf-succinctly.pdf#page=13&view=fitH

However the newest Edge with Acrobat (the upsell version) will not even go to page 13!

What you would need is a Binary plugin that uses search but then they will not usually use Java or JavaScript and ignore external commands except from the desktop client.

So how are we supposed to set the desired Adobe actions in a controlled manner such as a personal / corporate /enterprise setting. The answer is to add "nameddest" (and prepare a highlight) when presenting the file. then the following fragment will work, after you add those internal to PDF settings. The Browser will simply act on the filename and the PDF will act on the commands.
FileServer/folder/pdf-succinctly-chapter2.pdf#nameddest=Chapter2&view=FitH



Answer
After a few days of trial and error the only working solution using a fragment (similar to the question). Is ask your users to install the tracker web plugin. This will do exactly what is needed, in a browser.
It will look like this,

The necessary fragment is, https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/pdf/pdf-succinctly.pdf#page=13&FitH&highlight=350,700,115,145
